# Cygwin GCC Cross compiling binaries?

Tags: linux, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile linux binaries with cygwin on windows. Are there any precompiled linux-gcc binaries that are up to date? The page I found last updated in 07.

http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html

I thought cygwin would have come with cross compiling binaries but I guess not.

Comment: Do you really need the modern gcc? 3.3.4 is rather stable (I think, debian can accept this version).

Comment: GCC 4.x and GCC 3.x are *planets* apart from each others in optimizations and code conformance. I would do my best to avoid GCC 3.x when 4.x is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://sourceware.org/cygwinports has gcc-4.5.2 both for x86 and x86_64 Linux.